# Who or which academic paper first noted the death of a language every two weeks?

Tags: language-change, history, language-revival

One language dies every two weeks. But where does that statistic come from?
Everyone is saying it without explicit citation.

Who or which academic paper first noted the death of a language every two weeks?

- [One language dies every two weeks? What it means and what's being done about it](http://info.moravia.com/blog/bid/254901/One-language-dies-every-two-weeks-What-it-means-and-what-s-being-done-about-it) (from the blog "Moravia")
- [Google search for "how many languages are dying every day"](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=how%20many%20lnagugaes%20are%20dying%20everyday#q=how%20many%20languages%20are%20dying%20every%20day&spell=1)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, **`David Crystal`** (2000), see catdir.loc.gov/catdir/samples/cam032/99053220.pdf‎

Long citation:

> A middle position would assert 50% loss in the next 100 years. This is
>   the view independently arrived at by three linguists reported by
>   [Krauss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_E._Krauss) in 1992. 34 50% is 3,000 languages. 100 years is 1,200 months.
>   **To meet that time frame, at least one language must die, on average,
>   every two weeks or so**. This cannot be very far from the truth.

It's a conjecture of how language would die according to guess-gestion of other linguist's statistics **not reporting language death**.

Comment: The actual 1992 article by Krauss et al is currently available online, but I'm not sure if it will remain there: http://www.rnld.org/sites/default/files/Hale%20et%20al%201992.pdf